# Potentials performance issues with scala and elasticsearch

Tags: json, scala, elasticsearch

Hello StackOverflowers !

I got an elasticSearch document with the following structure, in order to be able to fetch the title translation for a specific language :

```
    {
        "contents": {
            "title": {
                "es": "hola",
                "fr": "bonjour",
                "de": "halo"
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that this structure is not easy to convert efficiently to scala case classes
( I don't want the name of the language to be the name of the key.. )

```
    case class Title(es:String, fr:String, de:String)
    case class Contents(title:Title)
    case class R00tJsonObject(contents:Contents)
```

I modified in consequence my document structure :

```
        "contents": {
            "title": [
                {
                    "lang": "es",
                    "value": "hola"
                },
                {
                    "lang": "fr",
                    "value": "bonjour"
                },
                {
                    "lang": "de",
                    "value": "Halo!"
                }
            ]
        }
```

so I can now store each translation as a list of tuples, like this :

```
    case class Title(lang:String, value:String)
    case class Contents(title:List[Title])
    case class R00tJsonObject(contents:Contents)
```

I request each language by executing this elastic search query, for exemple for the french  language :

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "term": {
                "contents.title.lang": "fr"
            }
        }, {
            "term": {
                "contents.title.value": "bonjour"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

What do you think about this modification ? Shoud I worry about potentials performance issues given that this query looks to have to browse all the array title in order to find the good translation ?

Need your advices :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough about Elasticsearch to know if your modification will really hurt performance, but it definitely looks ugly. I think the problem came from trying to match your JSON document to a case class. Instead, you should use a `Map`, mapping JSON like:

```
{
  "es": "hola",
  "fr": "bonjour",
  "de": "halo"
}
```

To a `Map[String, String]`, or even better, `Map[LanguageCode, String]`, where `LanguageCode` is an enumeration for the languages your application will support. This will keep your structure in Elasticsearch simple, while minimizing the amount of code in Scala you will have to change when adding new languages.